# The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it error

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm currently wondering how I can avoid this error from this snippet of code contained inside of a loop.

```
var seriesColour = new LinearGradientBrush();
JSColor color = null;

seriesColour.Dispatcher.Invoke((System.Action)(() =>
{
    seriesColour = _colourBrushes[field.SeriesColour];
    color = new JSColor()
    {
        linearGradient = new JSGradient()
        {
            x1 = (int)seriesColour.StartPoint.X,
            y1 = (int)seriesColour.StartPoint.Y,
            x2 = (int)seriesColour.EndPoint.X,
            y2 = (int)seriesColour.EndPoint.Y
        },
        stops = new object[]
        {
            new object[] { seriesColour.GradientStops[0].Offset,  RGBConvert(seriesColour.GradientStops[0]) },
            new object[] { seriesColour.GradientStops[1].Offset, RGBConvert(seriesColour.GradientStops[1]) }
        }
    };
}));
```

I seem to get the error in the title, whenever I refresh the page (run it the second time around). Anybody any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, no, that sure looks borken.  High odds that the brush is getting created on the wrong thread and its dispatcher doesn't actually invoke to the UI thread.  Use Application.Current.Dispatcher to get ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem that usually happens when you're trying to update your UI components from a thread other than the main thread.

The reason of your problem seems like that the `seriesColour` component is being created in a different thread (different from the UI thread) and maybe its `Dispatcher` object isn't invoking the UI thread (and you have a multithreading issue while trying to update something in the UI).

Use `seriesColour.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` to check whether the current thread owns the `seriesColour` component. If it owns it, everything is okay. Otherwise, do the work in the UI using:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
        seriesColour = _colourBrushes[field.SeriesColour];
        ...// your code here.
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind using a `Dispatcher` to have the SAME thread operating on everything.  Because you created `seriesColour` on lets say `ThreadA`, then when you call it's `Dispathcer.Invoke()`, its just calling it on `ThreadA`.

So, if one of the other components you are referencing was created on `ThreadB`, then you're going to have a problem.

So as @HansPassant suggested, try `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke()`.  However, I would think you would also want to create `seriesColour` within the `Invoke()` as well.